# commath, \dfrac and \tfrac

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, fractions

I'm using the `commath` package for its nice `\od` and `\pd` functions, but I find it uses `\tfrac` internally. It seems to have an 'if-then' clause to sometimes use `\dfrac` but it never does so in my tests:

```
test 1: \od{p}{x}\\
test 2: $\od{p}{x}$
test 3: \(\od{p}{x}\)
```

Or in `align` environments either. I don't see any options to control the package behavior. Should I just re-define `\od` and `\pd` in my preamble to behave the way I want?

Comment: Where do you want it to use `\dfrac`? It does so in display style `\[`...`\]`.

Comment: Most of my equations are in `align` environments. I use this by default. Should I be using something else?

Comment: So am I right in assuming you are interested in having more control over using `\dfrac` and `\tfrac`, and not necessarily an explanation of why this is the case. Are you interested in a redefinition that uses (say) starred `\od*`/`\pd*` for `\dfrac` usage, and `\od`/`\pd` for the `\tfrac` usage?

Comment: I guess I'm looking for both... The normal size fractions look better to me, so I'd like to use them with the simpler forms provided by `commath`. I can redefine the commands myself. I'm wondering if there is some way to do this for `commath` via an option that I've missed. At the same time, if I'm breaking a standard, I'd be happy for an explanation why I should be happy with it the way it is, and that I should change all my existing `\frac` to `\dfrac` or `\tfrac` instead...

Comment: Similarly, why does commath use one font for `\[` environments, and another for `\begin{align}`. Aren't they similar enviroments? I understand the difference for `$` and `\(` compared to `\[`.

Comment: I found that [`commath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/commath) supports forced style versions of their differentials via `\t`- and `\d`- variants. Is this what you might be after?

Comment: Perfect. I didn't recognize that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`commath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/commath) provides `\textstyle` and `\displaystyle` versions of its `\od` and `\pd` (and `\md`) commands:

- `\textsyle` override: `\tod` and `\tpd`
- `\displaystyle` override: `\dod` and `\dpd`

[image: textstyle and displaystyle overrides for \od nad \pd]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{commath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/commath
\begin{document}
\verb|Normal:| \par
test 1: \od{p}{x} \par
test 2: $\od{p}{x}$ \par
test 3: \(\od{p}{x}\) \par

\bigskip

\verb|\textstyle-version:| \par
test 1: \tod{p}{x} \par
test 2: $\tod{p}{x}$ \par
test 3: \(\tod{p}{x}\) \par

\bigskip

\verb|\displaystyle-version:| \par
test 1: \dod{p}{x} \par
test 2: $\dod{p}{x}$ \par
test 3: \(\dod{p}{x}\) \par
\end{document}
```

It would be possible to define your own commands doing the same with a slightly different interface (using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse), say) that could allow you some flexibility.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between the "Normal" version and the "textstyle" (t) version?  It took some serious squinting before I even noticed a difference.

Comment: @TysonWilliams: There is no difference. Perhaps what you see is an artefact from my viewer during the screen grab. `\tfrac` is a forced `\textstyle\frac`, while `\dfrac` is a forced `\displaystyle\frac`. The "normal" `\frac` is either `\textstyle` or `\displaystyle`, depending on the style it is used in. The same holds for the *-`\od` family above.

Comment: while `\frac` switches behaviour between displaystyle and textstyle `\od` (like almost all commath commands) is broken in that respect and does not usefully switch, only the forced `\tod` and `\dod` versions are really useful. (The comath commands all use `\ifinner` to switch between display and text style versions but that is not a useful test in math mode)