# Spacing after derivative operator in the commath package

Tags: spacing, math-operators

I am using the `commath` package to typeset the derivative operator "D" with the command `\Dif`. This work well *unless* I want to add subscripts or superscripts. In this case, the spacing after operator is too small and the exponent / index "touches" the operator:

[image]

where the first operator is created via `\Dif` and the second one via `\mathrm{D}` (full MWE see below).

Is there some way to "redefine" the `\Dif` command in order to fix the spacing?

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{commath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \Dif^2_x f(x) \\
  \mathrm{D}^2_x f(x)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `{\Dif\,}^2_x` will do it, but that might be a nuisance, and not generally applicable.

Comment: Is there a way to make this automatically happen in general? I.e. to make ``\Dif`` work as it currently does almost always, but to produce something like ``{\Dif\,}^2_x`` when sub/superscripts are used?

Comment: @AbeSchulte What's the problem in using the definition I proposed in my answer? The definition by `commath` is inherently wrong and should never be used.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/whats-the-proper-way-to-typeset-a-differential-operator

It seems there is quite a bit of disagreement regarding what exactly is "right" and therefore what is wrong. Unless you can cite a source, I really don't think you can say something is "inherently wrong", especially when an international organization entirely dedicated to stuff like this says otherwise (see the top answer of the linked post).

Comment: My suggestion:
`\renewcommand{\Dif}{\operatorname{D}}`

Comment: @AbeSchulte I wasn't referring to whether the `D` should be upright or slanted, nor to any other typographic aspect; I'm saying that the *definition* of `\Dif` given in `commath` is TeXnically wrong and the only way for making it work is to modify it.

Comment: Could you explain why `\DeclareMathOperator{\Dif}{D \!}` is TeXnically wrong, and why `\newcommand{\Dif}{\mathop{}\!D}` is superior (or point me to a place that explains this)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The definition of `\Dif` in `commath.sty` is

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Dif}{D \!}
```

which is simply wrong. The `\!` backspace is the cause of your problem. It's not the only part in `commath` that I consider wrong, so I can't recommend using the package.

A more correct definition would be

```
\newcommand{\Dif}{\mathop{}\!D}
```

that you can add to your document (with `\renewcommand` if you insist in using `commath`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Just out of curiosity - could you elaborate on why `commath` should not be used? If I exclude it, I better do so now (i.e. before relying on too many of its commands).

Comment: @Bernd See, for instance, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120379/4427

Comment: Ah, I see. I saw e.g. (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22076/can-i-have-a-flexible-partial-derivative-macro) that the `cool` package seems to accomplish some things imilar to `commath`. Do you also recommend avoiding this package, or is it "kosher"?

Comment: @Bernd I never used `cool`, so I don't know about it.

Comment: @egreg, what is your opinion about using the package esdiff for typesetting differentials?

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{commath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Dif^{^2}_{_x} f(x) \\
\mathrm{D}^{^2}_{_x} f(x)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using double sub- and superscripts to avoid kerning problems is never a good solution. It makes your equation much more difficult to read because of the smaller symbols and the text will get inconsistent if you use “normal” sub- and superscripts in other equations (or other contexts in the same equation).