# When to use `\left(` and when plain `(`?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, brackets

This is basically a follow-up to the comments on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120379/17237) which I couldn't find to be settled anywhere. I learned that you can write ordinary bracket simply using

```
f(x)
```

but that you can also use

```
f \left( x \right)
```

where the latter automatically adopts the brackets' size, *but* creates a space between the function and the bracket.

My question is: when is one supposed to use which version. Is the second version only used when the "content" of the bracket is *not* an argument of some function? What if it is a long and complex argument, where I want the brackets to be increasing in size? Would I then use

```
f \! \left( long expression \right)
```

or is there some other solution for this?

---

Edit: While I found some solutions regarding the space adjustment, I was still wondering when to use which approach, i.e. whether there are some "best practice rules" for this.

Comment: when you have content inside the bracket (say a fraction) that needs the bracket to be longer than normal.

Comment: I usually only use the \left and \right when latex doesn't yield a satisfying size for the brackets, e.g. when you have fractions or other large symbols such as integral signs inside those brackets.

Comment: @ADP  Yes, but I was wondering whether there are some "best practice" rules for this (or so) - take the example `f(sin(x)+cos(x))`, does this already require larger brackets?

Comment: Duplicate? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses/ Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1454/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-delimiters

Comment: In my opinion `f(\sin x+\cos x)` doesn't require larger parentheses. ;-) But even if you write `f(\sin(x)+\cos(x))` there's no need. In some cases it can be preferable to use `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` for greater clarity.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ah, I didn't see these questions and they indeed seem to be pretty similar. Should I delete my question? Or is there some way to close it?

Comment: We (users with more than 10k rep) can vote to close it. For searching, it's OK to keep it around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `\left` only when the largest default delimiter `\Biggl` is too small. The reason is that IMHO, `\left` rarely uses the correct size. Moreover, it introduces a spurious thin space around the delimiters; this can be solved using `\mleft...\mright` from `\usepackage{mleftright}`.
2. As for `f(sin(x)+cos(x))`, the correct form is of course `f(\sin x+\cos x)` :) but suppose you mean `f(g(x)+h(x))`. Then the usage of larger parentheses is not a clear thing and two good typographers might do it in two different ways. I use the following way:

   - Inline, never use anything larger than `\big`, so this would be `f\bigl( g(x)+h(x) \bigr)`, but likely `\bigl\{ f\bigl(g(x)+h(x)\bigr) \bigr\} _ {x\in[0,1]}`.
   - On display, I generally increase the size with every nested pair, unless it becomes too big.
     [image]
3. Fractions, sums, integrals: I personally do not mind things "sticking out" a bit of the delimiters. Hence I would use the following

   - Inline: `$ \bigl(\frac{1}{4}\bigr) = \bigl( \int_0^{1/2} dx \bigr)^{1/2} = \bigl( \sum_{i=2}^\infty 2^{-i} \bigr)^{1/2} $`
   - On display: `\[ \Bigl(\frac{1}{4}\Bigr) = \biggl( \int_0^{1/2} dx \biggr)^{1/2} = \biggl( \sum_{i=2}^\infty 2^{-i} \biggr)^{1/2} \]`
     [image]
4. Use `\begin{pmatrix}` and similar for column vectors and matrices (requires `\usepackage{amsmath}`)